# Multiprocessing, what does pool.ready do?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

Suppose I have a pool with a few processes inside of a class that I use to do some processing, like this:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init_(self):
        self.pool = Pool(processes = NUM_PROCESSES)
        self.pop = []
        self.finished = []

    def gen_pop(self):
        self.pop = [ self.pool.apply_async(Item.test, (Item(),)) for _ in range(NUM_PROCESSES) ]
        while (not self.check()):
            continue
        # Do some other stuff

    def check(self):
        self.finished = filter(lambda t: self.pop[t].ready(), range(NUM_PROCESSES))
        new_pop = []
        for f in self.finished:
            new_pop.append(self.pop[f].get(timeout = 1))
            self.pop[f] = None
            # Do some other stuff
```

When I run this code I get a `cPickle.PicklingError` which states that a `<type 'function'>` can't be pickled.  What this tells me is that one of the `apply_async` functions has not returned yet so I am attempting to append a running function to another list. But this shouldn't be happening because all running calls should have been filtered out using the `ready()` function.

On a related note, the actual nature of the `Item` class is unimportant but what is important is that at the top of my `Item.test` function I have a print statement which is supposed to fire for debugging purposes. However, that does not occur. This tells me that that the function has been initiated but has not actually started execution.

So then, it appears that `ready()` does not actually tell me whether or not a call has finished execution or not. What exactly does `ready()` do and how should I edit my code so that I can filter out the processes that are still running?

Comment: Why do you think that the `cPickle.PicklingError` means that?

Comment: @zwol I honestly don't. Rather, I think the error is a symptom of the actual problem, which was detailed in my question.

Comment: What I'm saying is I think your diagnosis of the actual problem is mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiprocessing uses `pickle` module internally to pass data between processes,
so your data must be *picklable*. See [the list of what is considered  picklable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), object method is not in that list.
To solve this quickly just use a wrapper function around the method:

```
def wrap_item_test(item):
    item.test()

class MyClass:
    def gen_pop(self):
        self.pop = [ self.pool.apply_async(wrap_item_test, (Item(),)) for _ in range(NUM_PROCESSES) ]
        while (not self.check()):
            continue
```

Comment: So then, would I just place the `wrap_item_test` at the top of the module which contains `Item`? Or is there something else I need to know?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question you asked, `.ready()` is really telling you whether `.get()` *may* block:  if `.ready()` returns `True`, `.get()` will *not* block, but if `.ready()` returns `False`, `.get()` *may* block (or it may not:  quite possible the async call will complete before you get around to calling `.get()`).

So, e.g., the `timeout = 1` in your `.get()` serves no purpose:  since you only call `.get()` if `.ready()` returned `True`, you already know for a fact that `.get()` won't block.

But `.get()` not blocking does *not* imply the async call was successful, or even that a worker process even started working on an async call:  as the docs say,

> If the remote call raised an exception then that exception will be reraised by `get()`.

That is, e.g., if the async call couldn't be performed *at all*, `.ready()` will return `True` and `.get()` will (re)raise the exception that prevented the attempt from working.

That appears to be what's happening in your case, although we have to guess because you didn't post runnable code, and didn't include the traceback.

Note that if what you really want to know is whether the async call completed normally, after already getting `True` back from `.ready()`, then `.successful()` is the method to call.

It's pretty clear that, whatever `Item.test` may be, it's flatly impossible to pass it as a callable to `.apply_async()`, due to pickle restrictions.  That explains why `Item.test` never prints anything (it's never actually called!), why `.ready()` returns `True` (the `.apply_async()` call failed), and why `.get()` raises an exception (because `.apply_async()` encountered an exception while trying to pickle one of its arguments - probably `Item.test`).